# Why do people make "aaagh" noises when they make an effort (e.g. trying to hit a ball hard)?

Tags: physiology, human-physiology

I'm referring to, for instance, grunting in tennis. It refers to how many tennis players make loud "aaagh" noises when hitting a ball. In daily life, people often also do this when trying to lift something heavy, and etc. Recently, I noticed cats also make a similar noise (albeit smaller) when they are jumping onto a level that they can only barely reach.

Thus, the question: are there biological reasons why people cannot help but make such noises when trying to do something physically challenging? Does making noises help them achieve it for physiological reasons, or only for psychological reasons?

I searched online and wasn't able to find an answer.

Comment: There's smattering of research papers published on the topic of grunting and physical exertion, including at least one on tennis. The ones I've skimmed seemed to have small sample sizes and focused on testing physical performance with and without grunting, not on the physiology of the act. Next time you do any kind of brief physical exertion, pay attention to what your body does naturally. Most people will inhale in preparation, briefly hold their breath at the moment exertion, and exhale through the motion. A sequence that seems to prime the body to grunt.

Comment: @MikeyC do you mind sharing the references you found? Thanks!

Comment: @MikeyC that breathing motion is called the Valsalva manoeuvre

Comment: @bob1 - The question is why do people grunt [when doing the Valsalva maneuver], not "What is it called when people take a deep breath, close their glottis and exhale against the closed glottis?"

Comment: This is not an opinion-based question; there is an answer (or are answers). I VTC because of lack of any research.

Comment: Mainly because they are English speakers - this kind of utterances is specific to a phonetic system and culture. E.g., Russians are more likely to use "ehhh/uhhh" when mzking an effort and "aye/oye" when simething hurts them (rather than "auch").

Comment: Hilarious. Agree with MikeyC and RogerVadim. Clearly the answer is so obvious, I don't think it requires a "real research answer", that's just woeful pedantry. It's not biology, just a consequence of physics. The answer to the question "why noise" is because noise/vocalization/phonation comes about when the glottis is partially closed. After closing it (Valsalva maneuver), air remains unexhaled, so remaining pressurized air follows with a vocalization as the glottis goes to a full relaxation state. Partial Valsalva maneuvers are also vocalized. A slackening glottis is the entire explanation.

Comment: @SPr - That is absolutely not "the entire explanation." Muscles groups are strengthened or not depending on if there is a grunt or no grunt (according to studies). It is indeed physiology, and physiology is part of Biology. So it is an unconscious attempt to strengthen oneself against a task. Maybe you should question your assumptions before declaring something "the entire explanation."

Comment: @anongoodnurse - I am aware of that. It was a hint to the OP of something they could research.

Comment: Thank you all. Why don’t some of you write a formal answer though?

Comment: @JLi Answer to your Q is strictly two-fold in my view: (i) people hold breaths to maximize output from muscles and afford higher rigidity, which is handy when you need leverage and power, by essentially increasing the pressure inside the torso; and (ii) people make the grunting noise because of the physics of vocalization, due to the relaxing of the glottis which must occur between holding breath and releasing breath to continue respiration. I think the semantic pedants should provide more than complaints to demonstrate that other factors are at play. Sometimes you have to provoke an answer ;)

Comment: @SPr Thanks, makes sense!